Standalone iMessage app on Xcode 16 beta doesn't appear in neither simulator nor device after installation
I created a standalone iMessage app using Xcode Version 16.0 beta 4
enter image description here
I didn’t write any code yet and I run the default Hello World program in a simulator iPhone 15(v 17.5)
enter image description here
However, nothing showed up in the iMessage. Did I miss anything?
